# 404 error when accessing Struts2 Web application

Tags: struts2, cvs

I had created a web application and committed the code in CVS. The web application is working good in my machine. When i tried to import the same code in another machine i am getting 404 error. I tried importing the code via ftp from my machine to another machine and also checking out the code from CVS. But still i get 404 error. 
I also noticed that there is no error that had been captured in the console or in the application's log. Could someone help me in how to proceed further in identifying the issue. Please let me know if i need to post any further details regarding the issue.

I notice this issue to be in the Websphere server. I tried hosting the application in different machine and found that in few machine the same code is working good and some it is not. Is there any way to compare the server configuration?

Comment: The issue is: the server is in your machine :)

Comment: I am not able to understand Andrea. I am hosting the application in the websphere server in the respective machine and hitting the respective URL. Still i get the 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WAS server 6.1 i added the below value in the web container and the application worked fine.
Steps:
    In the server admin console, click on Application Server-->  --> Web container--> custom properties. 
    Add the name as `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility` and value as `true`.

Thank you all for the response.